# How to set the PYTHONPATH per project in ATOM editor

Tags: python, jupyter, atom-editor, pythonpath, hydrogen

I wanted to replace [Jupyter Notebooks](http://jupyter.org/) with something which has a more IDE like feeling.

I stumbled upon [Hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen) which is a plugin for the [Atom Editor](https://atom.io/).

It worked ok, but since I use the [Cookiecutter directory layout](https://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/#directory-structure) I always had the problem that scripts I ran from my `src` folder needed other imports than the ones I used in the `notebooks` folder.

I tried a lot of other plugins like [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run) but I had the same problem. Depending on the directory where the script lived imports where not found.

Usually one would set the `PYTHONPATH` to add more folders for Python to search in, but I found no way to set the `PYTHONPATH` inside Hydrogen (ideally in a per project way).
`

Comment: You can install the Script extension. It will show up under the packages menu item and when selected the first option is run script.

Comment: I did try the Script extension too. You can't set a PYTHONPATH there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookiecutter has an .env-File in the root directory of the project.

I added the `PYTHONPATH` there (caveat: do not have spaces around the equal sign!) and installed the [load-dotenv-variables](https://atom.io/packages/load-dotenv-variables) plugin in Atom.

Now it is possible to start a script with hydrogen or atom-python-run independently of the current folder on a per-project basis.